# Setting a div to an array so i can make things disappear / re-appear based on buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

The title may not make the most sense.

Basically I want to store all of the ".mainContent" into X ..

Then when you'd click a button it would make x[0] display none, and bring in x[1].. if that makes sense... that way I could have the same wiping transition and it would just bring in my 4 different pages that I would have.

You can see my page here: I have the "home" and "learn more" pages hard coded, but I obviously don't want to have to do this for every section

http://mikecioffi-me.stackstaging.com/   (*this is not on mobile***) only desktop. mobile version is not ready.. haha

```
<script>
    var dissapearingTime = 1800;
var nextSlideTime = 3000;
var originalNumber = 0;
var newNumber = 1;
var x = $(this).find('.mainContent');

$('.button').hover(
  function () {
    $('.arrowRight').toggleClass('active');
  })

$('.button').click(
  function () {
    console.log(x);
    $('.sidebar').toggleClass('anim-trans');
    setTimeout(function () {
      $(".hero").css("display", "none");
      $(".blank").css("display", "block");
    }, dissapearingTime);

    setTimeout(function () {
      $('.sidebar').toggleClass('anim-trans');
    }, nextSlideTime);
  })

function hello() {
  $('.sidebar').toggleClass('anim-trans');
  setTimeout(function () {
    $(".blank").css("display", "none");
    $(".hero").css("display", "block");
  }, dissapearingTime);
  setTimeout(function () {
    $('.sidebar').toggleClass('anim-trans');
  }, nextSlideTime);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

i loved your animations :).

I don't know how you use that but you can do with this way. I hope it can help you.

```
myArray = $('.test');
$(myArray[0]).hide();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7rod0vky/2/

Answer (score 0):

one way would be to label each card / div / item with an id, and then you can hide display using a global namespace / json object / dictionary for your own page, that holds some extra info between scopes.

```js
window.__ok = {'current': '', 'prev': null}
var x = $('.main > div');
['#c0', '#c1', '#c2'].map(function(c,i,a){
  $(c).on('click', function(a){
      window.__ok.prev = window.__ok.current;
      window.__ok.current = i;
      alert(`show ${c} id: ${i} prev: ${window.__ok.prev}`);
      if ($(`#${window.__ok.current}`).css('display') == 'none'){
        $(`#${window.__ok.current}`).css('display', 'block');
        $(`#${window.__ok.prev}`).css('display', 'none');
      }
      
  })
})
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
  height: 30px;
  display: none
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 30px;
  display: none
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
  height: 30px;
  display: none
}

span {
  color: grey;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div id="0" class="red">a</div>
  <div id="1" class="blue">b</div>
  <div id="2" class="green">c</div>
</div>
<span id="c0">show0</span><br>
<span id="c1">show1</span><br>
<span id="c2">show2</span><br>
```